# Using CSS to style elements drawn to a canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

At the moment, we use hardcoded styles when writing text on a canvas:

```
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#2F353C";
    ctx.font = "15px 'Roboto', sans-serif";
    ctx.fillText(varName || '', 5, 12);
```

I would dearly love to store that actual style information in CSS files, and access it from there somehow. (I'm not expecting miracles, like CSS to magically apply to elements rendered within the canvas...)

The only way I can think of would be to create some text elements behind our canvas, assign them classes, and then somehow access their computed properties, transferring them to the canvas elements.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I've done hacks like creating special classes in CSS stylesheets for the site color scheme, and then creating on-page elements with each class so that I can (from JavaScript) get the color back from the DOM elements. I really wish there were a less horrible way of doing that.

Comment: Why add an expensive level of indirection (CSS-to-JS-to-canvas) when you can use the intended (and best) tool for the job: JavaScript?

Comment: For the obvious reason of wanting to keep all styling information in one place (and somewhere that designers can access it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning**

This answer should be removed but as it has been accepted I am unable to. Below is the answer as is, but there are a host of problems and browser compatibility issues, making this answer impractical.

**SVG markup for canvas**

If you use SVG images to render to the canvas you can add CSS style rules to the elements within the SVG and as long as you continue to render the SVG it will reflect all the rules, including animations and other time based FX.

**SVG markup with CSS**

```
<!-- within the SVG element -->
<svg>
<style>
/* CSS */
#buttonWhite {  /* ID name */
   fill:white;
   font-size:12px;
}
#buttonBlue {
   fill:blue;
   font-size:16px;
}
</style>
<text id="buttonWhite" x="100" y="100">I am white</text>
<text id="buttonBlue" x="100" y="200">I am blue</text>
</svg>
```

**Script**

```
// within the script
var svg = new Image();
svg.src = "SVG_URL.svg";

// once svg has loaded then display it on the canvas
ctx.drawImage(svg,0,0);
```

If you make changes to the CSS or SVG you need to rerender it to see the changes.

**UPDATE**

For more information on linking in CSS see MDN [SVG & CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/SVG_and_CSS)

I had made a mistake in the CSS forgetting that SVG has its own styles. I have corrected it by replacing `color` with `fill`.

Comment: Wow, great idea. Not quite sure what you mean by the `svg.src = ` line, though. Presumably I'd use use `document.createElementNS` and then `appendChild` to actually add my elemnts?

Comment: @markE me and SVG are barely talking, but sometimes it will fill a gap.

Comment: @SteveBennett Yes you are correct appending to the DOM is the safer option.

Comment: I have to disagree with you here and I'm wondering if any of you or the OP have tested it : svg in `<img>` doesn't load any external resources. That's the whole purpose of [my script](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap), and I won't be writing it otherwise :-) . The CSS has to be **inside** the element itself when  loaded into the `<img>` for it to get the resource (be it external CSS, elements, or images). So either change your answer with the svg markup containing the style tag, or only do apply inline styles on svg elements.

Comment: You will hate me... Thanks for the edit. I forgot to mention that the "animation and time based FX" part is also wrong... You are experiencing a [chrome bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74779) : see the `drawImage()` specs about animated resources : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts:canvasimagesource-3

Comment: @Kaiido Well that is one bug I hope they forget about. Around a year ago they had the same problem with gif images, it made it so easy to get all the gif frames, and then gone and I had to write a gif decoder. Anyways I see this answer is too problematic and I will just pull it down.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh I see you can not pull accepted answers. Well better put a warning on it then.

Comment: Yep, also I'm wondering what the advantages of hardcoding this into an svg file instead of in the js one. The only real benefits from this method is for all text-decoration that you can apply on svg text node, and that aren't implemented in canvas natively (underline,etc.) Unfortunately, FF doesn't support the letter-spacing attribute on those...